# How to build real time streaming application

Tags: reactjs, pusher

I am going to build application that shows real time data with React.
And I decided to use Pusher for real time data management.
I also trying to use open third party apis for getting data.
For example openweathermap for weather data.

My trouble is how can I know if the data from third party api is changed and let the Pusher know data is changed.

In one word, how can I make Pusher to connect third party apis?

Really want your help.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to check if the 3rd party API has realtime data support through websockets or not. If not you probably need to do a fetch calls at some interval of time to fetch the data  and update your application with it

Comment: Thank you innocent.
How to check if 3rd API supports real time data?

Comment: Check their documentation and lookout for something like websockets or realtime,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a system for it in Pusher but I don't know.

If it is possible for you, you can create a cron service that checks your 3rd API continually. But it has to be on a live service to run continually. If it detects any changes in the data, it can emit your client app by using Pusher, Socketio, etc.

Maybe the 3rd API provides this feature to you.

Comment: Thank you Halil.
Really appreciate your response.
But I am curious how to use cron service.
It would be great to detect data changes in 3rd API and send those changes to Pusher.
How can I do that?

Comment: @Branch Actually it is a long way :) We don't resolve your questions on this thread. I try to tell you about the process. The cron runs continually on a service that gets the data by using the API and then checks if the response is fresh or not. If the data is fresh, cron emits the data by using pushed or other services. But you have to store the data on any database to check the data. Maybe you can move forward step by step. First, you have to decide which language should you write it in. If you decide to write it with Nodejs,  you can examine cron packages on npm after the project is created

Comment: Are there any sample project that I can get help?